# The Remote Code for Nikon D40?

Tags: nikon, remote, nikon-d40

I have a Nikon-D40 and I want a remote control, but I want to build my own. I search on internet how to do it. Using Remote Control led and your smartphone you can build. But you need to Code or the Frequency of the signal for your own model in my case Nikon-D40. I try to find it on internet but I fail.

Comment: Perhaps this [thread](http://www.dpreview.com/forums/post/20577957) can be of some use.

Answer (score 1):

I friend of mine found a solution in this [site](http://www.bigmike.it/ircontrol/):

The frequency is **38,4KHz**